# used up my -(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:? how do i detect more collisions?

Tags: collision-detection, collision

I'm sorry if this is dumb but i'm baffled, and new to coding. I have a method to spawn meteorites which share the group "meteorites". I use collision detection method:

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair rocket:(CCNode *)nodeA meteorite:(CCNode *)nodeB{
```

to detect when the rocket collides with the meteorite. I also have a second type of meteorite that has a different effect. How can I now include that in the detection method without invoking the method call [self.spawnMeteorite] on the original meteorite?

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair rocket:(CCNode *)nodeA meteorite:(CCNode *)nodeB{
[self meteoriteRemoved:nodeB];
[self spawnMeteorite];
_score ++;
_scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that this was a dumb question. I had copied and pasted the method to see if you can just duplicate the method which didn't work because they were identical. After changing some of the parameters, I realised you can use more than one ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve, with different nodes.